# Karate-Gatling: Grouping same API in Gatling reports

Tags: scala, karate

I'm running Gatling test where I call feature file. In that feature file I have multiple scenarios that call same API. Example GET /address/uuid , GET /address/uuid2 , GET /address/uuid3.
Is there a way to group all 3 or more reports under one report in Global. uuid is part of PATH

I found that possibility is to do so in scala with Map. Is there any other way? Txn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look at the documentation on how to set "patterns" to group URLs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling/#karateprotocol

Something like this should work:

```
val protocol = karateProtocol(
  "/address/{uuid}" -> Nil
)
```